# How can I tell Virtual Box to make the serial port a part of the PCI bus (and not the ISA bus)?

Tags: virtualbox, serial-port, pci

I have installed Ubuntu on Virtual Box, and I have enabled a serial port:

[image]

I have found out that the serial port has been attached to an ISA bus and not to a PCI bus.

Is there a way to tell Virtual Box to make the serial port a part of the PCI bus?

Comment: What exactly are trying to achieve?

Comment: Check your setup against [this post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=26860). And what is the host?

Comment: Background information: Serial ports use legacy I/O addresses which were once realized on the ISA bus, but today usually use the [LPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Pin_Count) of the southbridge, or even newer replacements. Even if you manage to find a Virtual Box driver which pretends to be a PCI card with a serial port, to my knowledge there are no kernel drivers for this. So, why would you want serial ports on a (virtual) PCI card?